# I am getting name error while using tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making an app that would calculate area, tsa, lsa, volume, etc. for various shapes
but I am getting this error:

> NameError: name 'Square_Area' is not defined

but the function is exactly named same as the one in the line
I am so confused
this is the bit of code that is getting error

```
    # layout for area of square
    tsaf = Frame(root)
    saf = Frame(root)
    Label(tsaf, bg="gray", fg="blue", text="Square Area Calculator",
         font=("calibri", 18, "italic")).pack(fill="x", ipady=10)
    Label(saf, fg="red", text="Side of Square:",
          font=("calibri", 18, "italic")).grid(row=0, column=0, pady=30, padx=30)
    Label(saf, fg="red", text="Area of Square:",
          font=("calibri", 18, "italic")).grid(row=1, column=0, pady=30, padx=30)
    Entry(saf, fg="blue", borderwidth=6, textvariable=SquareSide,
          font=("comicsansms", 16, "bold")).grid(row=0, column=1, pady=30, padx=20, ipadx=50)
    Entry(saf, fg="blue", borderwidth=6, textvariable=SquareArea,
          font=("comicsansms", 16, "bold")).grid(row=1, column=1, pady=30, padx=20, ipadx=50)
    Button(saf, fg="blue", text="Get Area", activeforeground="red", borderwidth=4, command = 
    Square_Area,
          font=("comicsansms", 16, "italic")).grid(row=2, column=1, pady=30, padx=50, ipadx=50)
```

and this is the function the button is using

```
    def Square_Area():
        side = float(SquareSide.get())
        area = side*side
        SquareArea.set(f"{area}")
```

I have tried everything on my side if anyone can pls help
if you need the full code I am listing it below
i will remove the unnecessary part

```
    from tkinter import *
    
    root = Tk()
    
    # setting up window
    root.geometry("600x400")
    root.minsize(600, 400)
    root.maxsize(600, 400)
    root.title("Shape Calculator")
    
    # declaring variable
    SquareSide = StringVar()
    SquareArea = StringVar()
    
    # main page text
    mt = Frame(root)
    mt.pack()
    title = Label(mt, fg="red", text="Select any field that you want to calculate",
                  font=("arial", 18, "bold"))
    title.pack(padx=62, pady=185, side=LEFT)
    
    # layout for area of square
    tsaf = Frame(root)
    saf = Frame(root)
    Label(tsaf, bg="gray", fg="blue", text="Square Area Calculator",
         font=("calibri", 18, "italic")).pack(fill="x", ipady=10)
    Label(saf, fg="red", text="Side of Square:",
          font=("calibri", 18, "italic")).grid(row=0, column=0, pady=30, padx=30)
    Label(saf, fg="red", text="Area of Square:",
          font=("calibri", 18, "italic")).grid(row=1, column=0, pady=30, padx=30)
    Entry(saf, fg="blue", borderwidth=6, textvariable=SquareSide,
          font=("comicsansms", 16, "bold")).grid(row=0, column=1, pady=30, padx=20, ipadx=50)
    Entry(saf, fg="blue", borderwidth=6, textvariable=SquareArea,
          font=("comicsansms", 16, "bold")).grid(row=1, column=1, pady=30, padx=20, ipadx=50)
    Button(saf, fg="blue", text="Get Area", activeforeground="red", borderwidth=4, command = 
    Square_Area,
          font=("comicsansms", 16, "italic")).grid(row=2, column=1, pady=30, padx=50, ipadx=50)
    
    
    # menu functions
    # area functions
    def square_area():
        kill_frame()
        tsaf.pack(fill="both")
        saf.pack(side=LEFT, anchor="nw")
    
    # function to clear screen
    def kill_frame():
        mt.pack_forget()
        saf.pack_forget()
        tsaf.pack_forget()
    
    # getting results
    # area result functions
    def Square_Area():
        side = float(SquareSide.get())
        area = side*side
        SquareArea.set(f"{area}")
    
    # making the menu
    main_menu = Menu(root)
    # 2d shape area
    m1 = Menu(main_menu, tearoff=0)
    m1.add_command(label="Square", command = square_area)
    main_menu.add_cascade(label="Area calculator", menu=m1)
    
    root.config(menu=main_menu)
    
    root.mainloop()
```

i have removed everything about other shapes and just left the square part
sorry if its a bit messy

Comment: Reorder your code, and make sure that `def Square_Area(): [...]` comes before the offending line. Right now it comes later, and as Python practically just reads the file from the top, it can't know that there will be such function later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the function before you reference it. Since you are not using classes, you are doing procedural programming where python executes from top to bottom. You are referencing the function which is defined later, thus giving an error.

Define the function `square_area` anywhere before you reference it.

So you can do this:

```
from tkinter import *
    
root = Tk()

# setting up window
root.geometry("600x400")
root.minsize(600, 400)
root.maxsize(600, 400)
root.title("Shape Calculator")

# declaring variable
SquareSide = StringVar()
SquareArea = StringVar()
def square_area():
    kill_frame()
    tsaf.pack(fill="both")
    saf.pack(side=LEFT, anchor="nw")

def Square_Area():
    side = float(SquareSide.get())
    area = side*side
    SquareArea.set(f"{area}")
# main page text
mt = Frame(root)
mt.pack()
title = Label(mt, fg="red", text="Select any field that you want to calculate",
              font=("arial", 18, "bold"))
title.pack(padx=62, pady=185, side=LEFT)

# layout for area of square
tsaf = Frame(root)
saf = Frame(root)
Label(tsaf, bg="gray", fg="blue", text="Square Area Calculator",
     font=("calibri", 18, "italic")).pack(fill="x", ipady=10)
Label(saf, fg="red", text="Side of Square:",
      font=("calibri", 18, "italic")).grid(row=0, column=0, pady=30, padx=30)
Label(saf, fg="red", text="Area of Square:",
      font=("calibri", 18, "italic")).grid(row=1, column=0, pady=30, padx=30)
Entry(saf, fg="blue", borderwidth=6, textvariable=SquareSide,
      font=("comicsansms", 16, "bold")).grid(row=0, column=1, pady=30, padx=20, ipadx=50)
Entry(saf, fg="blue", borderwidth=6, textvariable=SquareArea,
      font=("comicsansms", 16, "bold")).grid(row=1, column=1, pady=30, padx=20, ipadx=50)
Button(saf, fg="blue", text="Get Area", activeforeground="red", borderwidth=4, command = 
square_area,
      font=("comicsansms", 16, "italic")).grid(row=2, column=1, pady=30, padx=50, ipadx=50)


# menu functions
# area functions

# function to clear screen
def kill_frame():
    mt.pack_forget()
    saf.pack_forget()
    tsaf.pack_forget()

# getting results
# area result functions


# making the menu
main_menu = Menu(root)
# 2d shape area
m1 = Menu(main_menu, tearoff=0)
m1.add_command(label="Square", command = square_area)
main_menu.add_cascade(label="Area calculator", menu=m1)

root.config(menu=main_menu)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: There are both `square_area` and `Square_Area` functions in the original code. You are right about that it's a simple ordering issue, but you are wrong about focusing on `square_area`.

Comment: @tevemadar, yeah. I can be a fool sometimes, like this one. Thanks!

Comment: I tried this method and it worked I don't know why I didn't thought about this